# copy/paste shortcuts not working in gedit and gnome-terminal

Tags: gnome-terminal, 16.10

After some updates in the system in general, `gnome-terminal` on my Ubuntu 16.10 stopped responding to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> shortcuts for copy and paste, neither with current clipboard buffer nor with visual selection buffer. Both shortcuts work fine in `XTerm`. Same keybindings are again not working in `gedit` and `xpad` but working properly on `google-chrome`. I tried changing the keybindings from `dconf-editor` but it didn't respond when I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> (i.e. no new accelerator is set).

Any help is appreciated.